# How to change timestamp for symbol link using golang?

Tags: go

`os.Chtimes` always to follow symlinks and change the real files timestamp.
Is there a method to change the symlinks timestamp in?

Just like `touch -h` does.

Comment: I'm not only want to refresh the timestamp, but to update the timestamp as a setting value. like touch -t 201203101513 -h symlink

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure it's possible, at least from the `syscall` package.

Looking at the source-code for say [syscall.Chtimes](https://golang.org/src/os/file_posix.go?s=3891:3956#L130):

```
func Chtimes(name string, atime time.Time, mtime time.Time) error {
    var utimes [2]syscall.Timespec
    utimes[0] = syscall.NsecToTimespec(atime.UnixNano())
    utimes[1] = syscall.NsecToTimespec(mtime.UnixNano())
    if e := syscall.UtimesNano(fixLongPath(name), utimes[0:]); e != nil {
        return &PathError{"chtimes", name, e}
    }
    return nil
}
```

duplicating this code - and removing the `fixLongPath` call which I assumed followed the symlinks - still affects the target file, not the source symlink.

Even trying this operation on a symlink which points to a non-existent file, returns a runtime error `no such file or directory`.

A `CGO` pkg - could, but that seems overkill.

Comment: This appears correct. I believe what would need to be done is to wrap the `lutimes` system call instead -- which is different from `utimes` in that it doesn't follow symlinks. Maybe there exists a go package that wraps that. A temporary patch would be to shell out to `touch -h`. Here is one [debate](https://grokbase.com/t/gg/golang-nuts/154wnph4y8/go-nuts-no-way-to-utimes-a-symlink) about how the fix should go.

Answer (score 1):

If you use linux, you can use `golang.org/x/sys/unix` package, which provides `Lutimes`

```
import "golang.org/x/sys/unix"

unix.Lutimes(symlink, nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a symlink exists and if so, remove it and create another one.

```
if _, err := os.Lstat(symlinkPath); err == nil {
  os.Remove(symlinkPath)
}

err := os.Symlink(filePath, symlinkPath)
if err != nil {
  fmt.Println(err)
}
```

Comment: I haven't described my question clear, I want to change the timestamp as I want. for example, change the symlink's timestamp to 2018/12/12 11:22:33